# How do I isolate the major white areas, Iterate through those contours, add a bounding box?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, contour

I'm am trying to get all white areas in the below image (first / second image), and draw a bounding box.

After thresholding, canny etc I get a decent mask, although needs improving. However not sure how to get all white areas once isolate. As you can see the current scrip finds the major contour (third image)

```
img = cv2.imread("img.png")
 
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
_, thresh = cv2.threshold(img_gray, 128, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
img_blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(thresh, (5, 5), 2)
img_canny = cv2.Canny(img_blur, 0, 0)

cnts = cv2.findContours(img_canny, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
r1, r2 = sorted(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea)[-3:-1]
x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(np.r_[r1, r2])
cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 0, 255), 2)
cv2.imshow("img", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

I have tried grabbing all contours using..., but still only adds a single box. This should sort big to small?

```
cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)
(cnts, _) = contours.sort_contours(cnts)

for C in cnts:
    if cv2.contourArea(C) < 200:
        continue
    box = cv2.minAreaRect(C)
    box = cv2.boxPoints(box) if imutils.is_cv2() else cv2.boxPoints(box)
    box = perspective.order_points(box)
    orig = img.copy()
    cv2.drawContours(orig, [box.astype("int")], -1, (0, 255, 0), 1)
    cv2.imshow("img", orig)
```

[image: Original]

[image: Desired white spaces] - Desired

[image: Result with single cnt detection]

To conclude, I'm trying to isolate the white spaces (yes needs some work), then add a box to all isolated white areas, eventually get box area etc.

Comment: Don't use Canny.  Why are you using it?  Simply threshold on the color you want using cv2.inRange() and get contours. You do not need edges to find region contours

Comment: welcome. [tour], [ask], [mre] please, including source data. plots are nice to look at but they are not data.

Comment: thanks but I only have the image im afraid, the top image.  The bottom image I produced with the code.